# How to make this header with tikz in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to make this header below with tikz in latex for use in tests at the school where I work.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `tcolorbox` be a better tool for that? It looks to me like an array of smaller `tcolorbox`es inside a larger one, all of which have some detached title.

Comment: I agree with Schrödinger's cat. @Itamar Barbosa de Lima, take a look at some examples os `tcolorbox` [here](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-example.pdf). The full documentation can be found in CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a start. Designing the boxes is not so difficult, but punching in the texts from a screen shot is cumbersome. The outer box is more or less the example from p. 127 of the `tcolorbox` manual and the inner boxes are variants thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,xparse]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,title=#2, 
fonttitle=\sffamily\small,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,boxrule=0.4pt,
coltitle=black,colback=white,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={colframe=white,colback=white,left=0.2pt,right=0.2pt},
#1}
\begin{document}
\tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=both,
enhanced,center,fonttitle=\sffamily\large\bfseries,
title=\textbullet~Nome da Escola~\textbullet,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}, 
boxed title style={left=2em,right=2em,top=1ex,bottom=1ex,boxrule=2pt,arc=1em},
coltitle=black,boxed title style={colback=white}, 
segmentation style=white,colback=white,colframe=black,width=\linewidth
]{% 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow,draw=yellow!75!red] (0,0) circle (1cm); \fill[red] (45:5mm) circle (1mm);
\fill[red] (135:5mm) circle (1mm);
\draw[line width=1mm,red] (215:5mm) arc (215:325:5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}{%
\begin{tabular}{r}
\begin{mybox}[width=14em]{Nome completo do Aluno(a)}
\end{mybox}~
\begin{mybox}[width=3em]{No}
\end{mybox}~
\begin{mybox}[width=7em]{S\'erie/Turma}
\end{mybox}\\[-2ex]
\begin{mybox}[width=8em]{Professor(a)}
\end{mybox}~
\begin{mybox}[width=8em]{Disciplina}
\end{mybox}~
\begin{mybox}[width=8em]{Data de prova}
\end{mybox}\\[-2ex]
\begin{mybox}[width=8em]{Bimeste}
\end{mybox}~
\begin{mybox}[width=16.67em]{Tipo}
\end{mybox}\\
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: do you think it can look like the model that is made in Inkscape?